# Transition kernels of diffusions: kernel properties

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-process, stochastic-differential-equations

**Question**: Suppose $Y_{t,x}$ is an Ito diffusion, i.e. the a.s. unique solution of the SDE
$$
dY_{t, x} = b(Y_{t, x})dt + \sigma(Y_{t, x})dW_t, \qquad Y_{0, x}=x,
$$
with $\sigma, b$ Lipschitz continuous.
We can define the family of "transition functions" $(P_t)_{t\geq0}$ of the process via
$$
P_t: \mathbb{R}^d \times \mathbb{B}(\mathbb{R}^d) \to [0, 1], (x, B) \mapsto \mathbb{P}(Y_t\in B | Y_0=x).
$$
How do we know, that $P_t$ is a transition kernel for each $t$, i.e. that
$$
P_t(\cdot, B): x \mapsto P_t(x, B)
$$
is measurable for all $B\in\mathbb{B}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ and
$$
P_t(x, \cdot): B \mapsto P_t(x, B)
$$
is a probability measure for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^d$? What assumptions do we need for that?
**Own effort**: I was trying to show the semigroup property of the transition semigroup $(P_tf)(x):=\mathbb{E}[f(Y_{t,x})]$, which can be traced back to the Chapman-Kolmogorov Equation, which in turn only makes sense for transition kernels, i.e. if the defined transition functions have the kernel properties. However, this is often just assumed/stated as for example in [Pavliotis, Stochastic Processes and Applications, p.35]. Is this obvious? I could understand the second part, i.e. that $P_t(x,\cdot)$ is a probability measure, since that might just be a consequence of there being a solution to the SDE for every x?

Comment: I guess you rather want to say $\,\mathrm d Y_{t,x}=...$ instead of $Y_{t,x}\,\mathrm d t=...$. The transition kernel is given by the solution of the [Fokker-Planck equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fokker%E2%80%93Planck_equation#Higher_dimensions). But without more information, you can't find a closed form.

Comment: Of course, sorry, I corrected that. I do not necessarily need a closed form, the statement that for all diffusions the statement that the transition functions defined above are indeed kernels would be enough. Do you know if there is such a statement? I.e. that the solution to the Fokker-Planck equation is continuous in x for example?

Comment: The fact that $P_t(x,B)=\mathbb P\{Y_t\in A\mid Y_0=x\}$ is a kernel, is well known... The fact that $P_t(x,\cdot )$ is a probability measure is obvious. The fact that $P_t(\cdot ,B)$ is measurable for all $B$ is more complicated and can be find in section 9.7 in the book "stochastic calculus" of Paolo Baldi (section 9.7 and theorem 9.9)

Comment: @Surb I was assuming it to be well known, but I did not find a source. Thanks a lot!